# $scope.$watch getting undefined new and old value angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
    <input
                  type="text"
                  datetime-picker
                  date-format="dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"
                  future-only
                  readonly
                  name="flg_{{user.user_id}}"
                  ng-model="orderItems[user.user_id].flg_time"
                  ng-click="saveOrder(user, orderItems[user.user_id])"
                  >
    <input
                  type="text"
                  datetime-picker
                  date-format="dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"
                  future-only
                  name="dep_{{user.user_id}}"
                  ng-model="orderItems[user.user_id].dep_time"
                  ng-click="saveOrder(user, orderItems[user.user_id])"
                  >

    var userInfo = auth.getCurrentUser().children;

     angular.forEach(userInfo, function(item, key){
      $scope.$watch('[orderItems[item.user_id].flg_time, orderItems[item.user_id].dep_time]', function(newVal, oldVal){
      console.log("N", newVal); // undefined
      console.log("O", oldVal); // undefined

      if (newVal !== oldVal && typeof oldVal !== 'undefined') {

    var orderItems = {
        'order_id' : $scope.order.order_id,
        'flg_time' : newVal[0],
        'dep_time' : newVal[1],
    }
    $scope.saveOrder(item, orderItems);
      }
    }, true);

  });
```

What i want to set value of new value into the original text box but it always says old and new value is undefined it should return the input value please guide what's wrong in it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can add $watch on $scope variables only, not other variables.

Answer (score 0):

instead of $scope.$watch use $scope.$watchcollection,because $watch only uses for 1 element if you go array elements than watchollection is better
Hope it helpsfull.

Comment: i think so,$watchgroup and $watchCollection are same.

Comment: you use $scope.$watch in angular.foreach, i think thatswhy its not working,so please try to write outside the method,than it works fine because watch method invokes whenever values changes.

Comment: the problem is here ng-model="orderItems[user.user_id].dep_time"

if i write  ng-model="orderItems.dep_time" and then watch orderItems.dep_time it works